# Предикат для find_if

Tags: c++, stl, предикат

Как можно создать предикат с двумя параметрами на входе. Например

```
bool (string &obj, char l)
{
    if (obj[0]==l) return true;
    return false;
}

list<string> list1;
list<string>::iterator p1=find_if(list1.begin(), list1.end(),initial(???));
```

Comment: initial это функция bool

Comment: В такой форме вопрос бессмыслен. `std::find_if` принципиально требует унарного предиката.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например,

```
char l;
...

... find_if(list1.begin(), list1.end(),
            [l](const string& obj){ return obj[0]==l; })
```

Вот полный вариант: https://ideone.com/dzxOFa

Comment: спасибо все работает

Comment: Ну, тогда закрывайте вопрос, приняв ответ :)